# Sanity with Next.js Error: Missing environment variable: SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET

Tags: next.js, sanity

During application development I've encountered the following error:

```
Error: Missing environment variable: SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET
```

The code for loading environmaental variable is as follows:

```
export const apiVersion = process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_API_VERSION || "2023-12-03";

export const dataset = assertValue(
  process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET,
  "Missing environment variable: SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET"
);

export const projectId = assertValue(
  process.env.SANITY_STUDIO_SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  "Missing environment variable: SANITY_STUDIO_SANITY_PROJECT_ID"
);
```

What could be an issue here? I have tried updating sanity and sanity CLI and made sure that the project ID is correct, but the error persists.

Answer (score 0):

In NextJS, Environment Variables that are meant to be used client-side must have a `NEXT_PUBLIC_` prefix:

- `SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET` will be available only server-side; client-side will resolve to `undefined`
- `NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET` will be available both server- and client-side.

**Source:** https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/configuring/environment-variables#bundling-environment-variables-for-the-browser

> Word of caution: This system is in place to make sure you're aware of
> the **risks of bundling variables in the client code**: they become
> public, so only use variables that are meant to be used in the
> browser; otherwise, it's recommended to use API endpoints (or in case
> of NextJS, Server Actions) to protect sensitive variables like API
> keys.

Comment: Despite changing the environment variable to NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_STUDIO_DATASET, the issue is still not resolved, with the same error message.

Comment: You may need to restart your dev server for the changes in env variables to take place. Also, I’d make sure in general you set the variables correctly, eg. your .env file is set up, other variables can be accessed etc